# Application.Sum result is wrong

Tags: vba, excel

I want to sum a column of a table for further calculations on the macro, but the result I get on Range("eq_asis") = 1.00 when it should give me a result of 0.00

What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub cambios_combobox()
Dim librito As Worksheet
Dim celda As Range

Set librito = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Tabla Paquetes")
Set celda = Range("A40")
'Range("Table1[[#All],[Column1]]").Select
    Select Case ComboBox1.Text
        Case "Deco"
            Range("eq_asis").Value = Application.Sum(librito.Range("Tabla2[Asistente fotografía]").Select)
        Case "Moda"
            celda.Value = 122
        Case "SODIMAC"
            celda.Value = 121
        Case "Multimarca"
            celda.Value = 120
        Case "Belcorp"
            celda.Value = 119
    End Select
End Sub
```

Tried DSum to no avail (not defined sub error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what happens when you pass in nothing to the sum function for some reason. You are passing in the result of the `Select` method which is null. You want to pass in a `Range` object

```
Range("eq_asis").Value = Application.Sum(librito.Range("Tabla2[Asistente fotografía]"))
```